# Extract part of string matching pattern - regex, close but no cigar

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string that can be very long and contain various lines and characters.

I am wanting to extract all lines that are surrounded by SB & EB:

```
SB1EB
SBa description of various lengthEB
SB123.456.78EB
SB99.99EB
SB99.99EB
SB2EB
SBanother description of various lengthEB
SB123.456.00EB
SB199.99EB
SB199.99EB
3
another description of various length that I don't want to return
123.456.00
599.99
599.99
SB60EB
SBanother description of various length that i want to keepEB
SB500.256.10EB
SB0.99EB
SB0.99EB
another bit of text that i don't want - can span multiple lines
```

This is the pattern I am using in PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/SB(\d+)EB\nSB(\w.*)EB\nSB(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2})EB\nSB(\d.*)EB\nSB(\d.*)EB\n/', $string, $matches)
```

So this should hopefully return:

```
[0] -> SB1EB
SBa description of various lengthEB
SB123.456.78EB
SB99.99EB
SB99.99EB

[1] -> SB2EB
SBanother description of various lengthEB
SB123.456.00EB
SB199.99EB
SB199.99EB

[2] -> SB60EB
SBanother description of various length that i want to keepEB
SB500.256.10EB
SB0.99EB
SB0.99EB
```

But I'm obviously doing something wrong because it isn't matching anything.  Can somebody help please?

SOLUTION:

Based on @Sajid reply:

```
if (preg_match_all('/(?:SB.+?EB(?:[\r\n]+|$))/', $string, $result)) {

    for($i=0;$i<count($result[0]);$i++){

        $single_item = $result[0][$i];
        $single_item = str_replace("SB","",$single_item);
        $single_item = str_replace("EB","",$single_item);
        if (preg_match('/(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2})/', $single_item)) {

            $id = $single_item;
            $qty = $result[0][$i-2];
            $name = $result[0][$i-1];
            $price = $result[0][$i+1];
            $total = $result[0][$i+2];

        }

    }

}
```

It's a bit messy, but it works! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@Sajid reply](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7947236/367456):

```
if (preg_match_all('/(?:SB.+?EB(?:[\r\n]+|$))/', $string, $result))
{
    for ($i=0; $i<count($result[0]); $i++)
    {
        $single_item = $result[0][$i];
        $single_item = str_replace("SB","",$single_item);
        $single_item = str_replace("EB","",$single_item);
        if (preg_match('/(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2})/', $single_item))
        {
            $id = $single_item;
            $qty = $result[0][$i-2];
            $name = $result[0][$i-1];
            $price = $result[0][$i+1];
            $total = $result[0][$i+2];
        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit messy, but it works! :)

Comment: Site telling me I have to wait - "You can accept your own answer in 4 hours..."

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack, but this will do the job:

```
$a = array();    
if (preg_match_all('/(?:SB.+?EB(?:[\r\n]+|$)){5}/', $x, $a)) {
    print_r($a);
}
```

Note that ?: is used to make the group non-capture, and the results will be in $a[0] (eg, $a[0][0], $a[0][1], $a[0][2] ...)

Comment: Thank you, this is very close but as some SB & EB lines won't always be in groups of 5, the resulting array is disjointed.  I do want to match only the lines that start with SB and are 5 lines long though, but only if they match the pattern in my (wrong) regex:
`SB(integer)EB\n
SB(text)EB\n
SB(number in format 000.000.00)EB\n
SB(decimal)EB\n
SB(decimal)EB\n`

Comment: I've got the data that I needed based on your solution, but without the {5} part.  Thank you - I'll add my solution to my post, it's a bit of a hack, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/SB\d+EB.*?(?=(?:SB\d+EB)|$)/s', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```

So basically what I am doing (based on your input) is simply checking the "header" string SB\d+EB as an entry point and consuming everything until I find another "header" or the end of the input. Note the /s modifier so that . matches newlines.

**Explanation:**

```
# SB\d+EB.*?(?=(?:SB\d+EB)|$)
# 
# Options: dot matches newline
# 
# Match the characters “SB” literally «SB»
# Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
#    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Match the characters “EB” literally «EB»
# Match any single character «.*?»
#    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=(?:SB\d+EB)|$)»
#    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(?:SB\d+EB)»
#       Match the regular expression below «(?:SB\d+EB)»
#          Match the characters “SB” literally «SB»
#          Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
#             Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
#          Match the characters “EB” literally «EB»
#    Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «$»
#       Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't working due to the fact that there can be other lines between my sample that I don't want to return.  I've updated my sample to show this. I only want to return the lines that start with SB and not the ones that don't.

Comment: @SammyBlackBaron let me get back to it ;)

Comment: @SammyBlackBaron do you want to capture specific lines? This is much easier than wanting to capture blocks of multiline text. Let me know.

Comment: this is basically a string of product details formatted into new lines. I am wanting to return Qty, Name, ID, Price, Total, so it has to be 5 lines and only the products that I want are surrounded by SB & EB 'tags'.  As I mentioned in another comment, this is the format of the chunk of text that I want to extract:
`SB(integer)EB\n SB(text)EB\n SB(number in format 000.000.00)EB\n SB(decimal)EB\n SB(decimal)EB\n`
Would it help if I stripped out the \n newlines so that it is just one long single line string? Then match the pattern similar to my original (wrong) regex? Thanks for help